# php.ini error syntax while line is comment

Tags: php, syntax, directadmin

I want to install SSH2 on DirectAdmin.
After install when I want to edit php.ini I try to find it:

```
#/usr/local/bin/php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in /usr/local/php54/lib/php.ini on line 339
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php54/lib/php.ini
```

I get syntax error 339 while line is comment (php.ini file : http://pastebin.com/dZ6P9M2v)

How can I fix it?
Also how to add ssh2 extension in php.ini.

Comment: try to use `;` instead of `#`

Comment: There is no '&' in the line 339 could you please open your file with nano -c /usr/local/php54/lib/php.ini   copy and post the line 339 in a comment

Comment: ; realpath_cache_ttl = 120
This is my problem it is commented line with no &

Comment: did you tried to restart apache `service apache2 restart`

Comment: After I try service httpd restart:after httpd restart: [root@server custombuild]# /usr/local/bin/php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/ssh2.so ' - /usr/local/ssh2.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/htscanner.so' - /usr/local/htscanner.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php54/lib/php.ini

Comment: I cannot really get it, beacause if you are trying to find your php.ini file you cann just type under root       `find / -name php.ini`